# VBA, extract file names from unformatted sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet filled with files I would like to extract. They exist in column A:D but are scattered throughout the sheet. Also have blank rows in between and other text. (It's a bunch of code). Does anyone have any strategies for extracting these file names ? Row by row is tedious , filtering doesn't work due to blanks, however each file name starts with a "/home" usually.

Comment: You can use filter to filter away blank rows (yes its working) and then you can use row by row on less rows.

Comment: When I try to filter , I only get the options for blanks. I uncheck it and doesn't take out the blanks.

Comment: try to select whole column. I recorded this easy macro, so you can try it yourself     `Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$3:$B$21").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"` but can be written much better

Comment: What does this do ? Filter out blanks ?

Comment: yes. but you need to update range, so it will works on your example

Comment: Do the file names all have forward slashes, and are the filenames that you want to extract the only things which have such slashes? Do they all have a dot? In other words -- are they the only things in the range that are `Like "*/*.*"`? Also -- what do you mean by "extract"? Extract to *where*?

Comment: Yes they are the only things that have "/" , they either start like `"/home` or `/home`  . and yes they have dots in the path i.e .DONE or .CSV .   And by extract I mean extract and put to sheet 2, just to separate them.

Comment: Do you want to *copy* them to sheet 2 or *move* them to sheet 2?

Comment: @JohnColeman , Copying works, just so I have a list of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx), you can use `.Find` in a loop to iterate over cells that contain values of a certain type:

```
Sub ExtractFileNames()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim R As Range, c As Range, copyTo As Range
    Dim startCell As String

    Set copyTo = Sheets(2).Range("A1")
    Set R = Intersect(Sheets(1).UsedRange, Sheets(1).Range("A:D"))

    Set c = R.Find("*/*.*")
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        startCell = c.Address
        Do
            copyTo.Value = c.Value
            Set copyTo = copyTo.Offset(1)
            Set c = R.FindNext(c)
        Loop Until c Is Nothing Or c.Address = startCell
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow works great! Just have a question, can you explain the "*/*." part? Does it search for both these in a string?

Comment: `*` is a wildcard in `Find`. It matches any string, including the empty string. Thus `"*/*.*" matches any string that contains a forward slash followed sometimes later than a dot. In your examples, the strings *started* with `/`, so I could perhaps have just used `"/*.*" -- but since `*` can match the empty string it doesn't hurt to include it.

Comment: Thanks John, how do I add wildcards? Reason being, the macro extracted 51/54 file names properly. The 3 files i missed didnt have a period. Say I want to add an _ , would this be recommended? Sometimes _'s may be before or after the dots. Perhaps I could just search for the / ?

Comment: Just use `*/*` if all of the strings and only the strings you are searching for have `/`

Comment: If I wanted to state another find, such as a word, how could I do this but into column B of the results sheet?

Comment: @Ladiesman191 Change `Set copyTo = Sheets(2).Range("A1")` to `Set copyTo = Sheets(2).Range("B1")`

Comment: Do I have to add another find? To get two at once? or 3 extracts at once?

Comment: @Ladiesman191 Just experiment. If you want to find strings with a different pattern you probably need a second loop.